# unable to import xlsx writer in Django

Tags: python, django, xlsxwriter

Problem to Solve:

-export selected models data to xlsx format from django admin.

Tried Solutions:

-Using xlsxwriter. I tried to install it in my django Environment using.

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xlsxwriter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xlsxwriter
```

Argument:

I have used xlsx writer in many python code before and as django is a python framework it should work in this as well but I don't understand why this error is popping up.

Comment: What _else_ does the error message say?

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
pip install XlsxWriter
```

Comment: which version of pip are you using? which python version? are you behind a proxy server? Can you install any other package?

Comment: You can also download the package directly and install it. https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/#files

Comment: My version of pip is 20.0.2 and python 3.8. I am able to install all other packages.